# Live Agent chat window in salesforce communities

Tags: community, liveagent

I have enabled Live Agent in Salesforce. I am having Salesforce communities for my partner users. Now I want my partner users to be able to chat with other Salesforce users. Can it be done?

Comment: do you mean chatter chat ?

Comment: I want a chat window to be visible to partner users by which then can chat to salesforce users.

Answer (score 1):

There is no standard way but you can put your code in Communitie's Footer under Community Branding section and it works.

Comment: Could you elaborate on this a bit? How exactly could you do that?

Comment: You can create a file and attach that in the document tab and then attach that in footer in the community branding page in administration.

Answer (score 0):

You can create a file and attach that in the document tab and then attach that in footer in the community branding page in administration.